# Locate new created directory of Ionic Native - File

Tags: android, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to save some form inputs on my device(in a new file) so I can be able to copy or send that file to someone.

Relevant code using is:

```
    this.file.checkDir(this.file.dataDirectory, 'mydir')
    .then(_ => console.log('Directory exists'))
    .catch(err => {.log('Directory doesnt exist');
      this.file.createDir(this.file.dataDirectory,"mydir",true);
});
```

The thing is that code works, the first time when it runs can't find the directory so it creates it. All good but the problem that I can't find my new created directory on my Internal storage.

I've read this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/listing-and-viewing-files-in-cordova-file-datadirectory-cordova-file-cachedirectory/90291) and I'm kinda disappointed if that is true. Anyone having experience with **Native FIle** and could help me? Thanks

P.S. I've forgot to mention that my app is not build for production, I'm using `ionic cordova run android`

Answer (score 1):

ok, the [solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/file-not-visible-when-using-ionic-native-file/58599)  was to use `this.file.externalDataDirectory` instead of `this.file.dataDirectory` that worked without having an external card. The path for the new created directory is here: `YourDevice\Android\data\io.ionic.starter\files`.